# Android ListView element

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make a `ListView` of view elements that should all be a full page size in the style of facebook newsstream. I can't seem to figure out how to set the sizes of each `ListView` element to be a full page size. Every `android:layout_heigh`t is set to `match_parent`. If i set it to `500dip` it is close to full page but that doesn't seem like good design to me.

Comment: Please post the relevant code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible with the current ListView. You might have to write a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood well your question you must use

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```